# How many palindromes are there in the range $0000$ to $9999$?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, palindrome

*Apologies if this is a basic question, but my math is weak and this is something I've been wondering lately.*

[This viral Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/samantha.riddle.58/posts/10205834378013276) repeats a [long-standing](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/reverse-pin-atm-alarm/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social) myth that states:

> If a thief forces you to take money out of an ATM, do not argue or
>   resist. What you do is punch in your PIN number backwards. If it's
>   1234, you'll type  4321. When you do that, the money will come out but
>   will be stuck in the slot. The machine will immediately alert the
>   local police without the robbers knowledge and begin taking photos of
>   the suspect. Every ATM has the feature. Stay safe.

Obviously, this is incorrect, and downright irresponsible. But it's maybe easiest debunked by illustrating just how many PIN numbers would be the exact same if they were reversed, and this got me wondering what exactly that number was.

Pin numbers for banks are generally $4$ digits long and have the possible range of $0000$ to $9999$, which is a total of $10,000$ possible combinations. In as simple terms as possible for someone who's studied very little math, how do I work out how many palindromes are in this range?

Comment: Are you including things like $0110$ as palindromes?  And $0000$? If so, then you need to choose the first and second digits, so there are $10^2=100$ choices.  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: The number of $4$-digit strings which are palindromes: they all appear as $XYYX$.  Pick what the value of $X$ is (*ten options.  note, in choosing $X$ it simultaneously sets the value of both the first and last digit*).  Then pick the value of $Y$.  Apply multiplication principle to learn there are $10\times 10 = 100$ 4-digit strings which are palindromes.

Comment: Compare this to counting how many 4-digit strings there are in the first place: choose the first digit, the second, third, and fourth to get there are $10\times 10\times 10\times 10 = 10000$, as you already knew from other methods.

Comment: @lulu Those would all count as palindromes as far as I can tell, yes. I've edited the question with more background.

Comment: Ok, so then $100$ is the answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz I think I'm following you for the most part, except that I'm confused why if X is 10, XYYX would be only 10 x 10. Does the Y between the 10s not get multiplied with them?

Comment: We have the following ten possibilities for $X$:  $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,8,9\}$.  There are ten possibilities for $X$.  Ten is not one *of* those possibilities however.

Comment: If perhaps you were thinking that we have $10$ options for the first digit, and then we additionally have $10$ options for the final digit... that is not the case.  For palindromes, once we have selected the value of the first digit, the final digit only has one option.  The final digit *must be* the same as what we picked for the first digit.  Although the option itself will change based on what was selected earlier, the *number of options* does not change and will always be one.

Comment: @JMoravitz I did assume it was the latter case. But I suppose it isn't each instance of X and Y that are being multiplied in XYYX, but simply one of each. XX = 10 and YY = 10.

Comment: Quite.  [Rule of product on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).  A brief description is, if you want to count how many of an object there are and you can uniquely describe each object being counted via a sequence of steps such that the *number* of options available at each step do not depend on the previous selections (*though the options themselves may depend on earlier selections*), then the total number of objects is equal to the product of the number of options for the steps.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks a lot for your help, it's much appreciated. If you're willing to collate what you've said in these comments in an answer I'd be happy to select it as the best one.

Answer (score 2):

A 4 digit palindrome is uniquely determined by the first 2 digits.  Since there are 100 such combinations, there are 100 such palindromes.